# How do I add an "enviroment" to my scene in 3ds MAX?

Tags: maps, environment, max, graphics, 3ds

I'm Currently working on a scene and i cant seem to find infomation as to how to make a setting for my scen. Its basically a street with buildings on either sides. about 500m long.
I want to put it into a city "enviroment" for animation. Also there will be camera movements so i dont think simply adding an image as a background will work. what i want to know is, Is there a a way to achieve what i want without actually building a small city?
any help or a pointer in the right direction would be great.
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

A cubemap might work.  http://wiki.polycount.com/CubeMap

Answer (score 0):

There are applications which will generate a city for you, based on criteria you enter.  You can enter the building types, sizes etc.  I've used one called [City Engine](http://www.esri.com/software/cityengine) - I used the built in wizards to create this but you can create one from scratch even specifying the road layouts:  [Youtube Video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ccLX9PxMeRY)

Answer (score 0):

3ds max has predefined models within it's system,

For example a tree:
This tutorial is great:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G-cfF2ep2DI

look into "AEC Extended"